# choose from a list with xstring

Tags: xstring

I want a command that does the following:

```
\variation{1}{aaa;bbb;ccc} ----> aaa
\variation{2}{aaa;bbb;ccc} ----> bbb
\variation{3}{aaa;bbb;ccc} ----> ccc
```

The string in the second input can be a list with as many ; as needed (perhaps none at all), not just three as shown. I have almost got what I needed using xstring but it contains superfluous inputs and notation and is basically not elegant!

```
\newcommand{\variation}[3]{\StrBetween[#1,#2]{;#3;}{;}{;}}
```

Hence this is what I get

```
\variation{1}{2}{aaa;bbb;ccc} ----> aaa
```

It's the second input is the superfluous one.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution with `xstring` and eTeX's `\numexpr`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand*{\variation}[2]{%
  \StrBetween[{#1},{\numexpr(#1)+1\relax}]{;#2;}{;}{;}%
}

\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  \detokenize{#1} $\rightarrow$ #1%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\ttfamily
\test{\variation{1}{aaa;bbb;ccc}}\\
\test{\variation{2}{aaa;bbb;ccc}}\\
\test{\variation{3}{aaa;bbb;ccc}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Update

- \StrBetween knows a final optional argument, that allows to store the result in a macro.
  Because I did not know, how `\variation` is used, the macro inherited the final
  optional argument. The usual looking for optional arguments in LaTeX (based on `\@ifnextchar`) removes following white spaces to find the opening square bracket. `\relax` stops the looking for `[` and the space after the argument braces of `\variation` 
  is kept.
- Second problem from the comments: Package `xstring` adds spaces (uncommented line ends) after numerical comparisons. In case of explicit numbers, the space is ignored and the parsing of the number finished. But if the number is given by an integer register or in this case by a complete `\numexpr`, the space is not needed and kept.

  There are several ways to cure this:

  - Bug report.
  - `\the\numexpr` instead of `\numexpr`
  - Expanding the arguments and convert to explicit numbers before. Then `\StrBetween` only sees the expanded numbers.

New test file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand*{\variation}[2]{%
  \edef\variationNext{%
    \noexpand\StrBetween[%
      \the\numexpr(#1)\relax,%
      \the\numexpr(#1)+1\relax
    ]%
  }%
  \variationNext{;#2;}{;}{;}\relax
}

\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  \detokenize\expandafter{\string#1} $\rightarrow$ [#1]%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\ttfamily
\test{\variation{1}{aaa;bbb;ccc}}\\
\test{\variation{2}{aaa;bbb;ccc}}\\
\test{\variation{3}{aaa;bbb;ccc}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This works a treat! But what's eTex?

Comment: @Geoff See [The eTeX manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/e-tex/v2/doc/etex_man.pdf). You have it already, because package `xstring` requires it.

Comment: I have seen that your macro (albeit one now modified by me) gives an unwanted space.    `\newcommand*{\variation}[2][1]{\StrBetween[{#1},{\numexpr(#1)+1\relax}]{;#2;}{;}{;}\xspace}`. Now `hello \variation[1]{aaa;bbb;ccc} world` doesn't typeset as it should `hello aaa world`.

Comment: @Geoff Remove `\xspace`, it does not make any sense here, because the space after the argument braces is already kept.

Comment: Without the \xspace I get as output hello aaaworld. It is the space between hello and aaa that is too large.

Comment: `\StrBetween` supports a final optional argument. The scanner for the optional argument removes the space. Adding `\relax` instead of `\xspace` solves the problem.

Comment: Ok, the \relax solves the after problem; but there is still too much space before. I tried a relax there too but this didn't do anything.

Comment: I see the update has solved all problems. Thanks for the complete solution.

Comment: Bug report/feature request is sent to the author of `xstring`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an option using `xparse/expl3` rather than `xstring` (if you're only interested in an `xstring` solution, then just take this as comparison).  The `variation` macro takes an optional first argument that determines the character to split the list at, the default is `;`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn {variation}{index~out~of~bounds}{You~have~requested~an~item~that~doesn't~exist}

\NewDocumentCommand{\variation}{ O{;} m m }
 {
    % split arg #3 at every occurrence of #1 (default #1=;) and store in sequence
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}{#3}

    % compare arg #2 to the length of the sequence
    \int_compare:nTF {#2>\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq}

        % if arg #2 > sequence length, then the item doesn't exist
        {\msg_warning:nnn {variation}{index~out~of~bounds}{}}

        % if arg #2 <= sequence length, then return requested item.
        {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#2}}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\variation{3}{aaa;bbb;ccc;ddd;eee}
\variation{1}{aaa}
\variation{2}{aaa}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1; it would be easy to add a test for a too large first argument.

Comment: I cannot get your example to work. It gives me an empty document.

Comment: @egreg warning added :)

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for you Geoff, are you getting any errors?  You may need to manually add the `xparse` and `expl3` packages if your setup doesn't add missing packages on the fly.

Comment: @Geoff It may be that your TeX distribution is too old. What are you using?

Comment: xparse is ok (I did look at this as a possibility, but it all looked rather complicated). What's the exp13?

Comment: @egreg I only updated about a month ago.

Comment: @Geoff If you have an updated TeX Live 2012 it will work.

Comment: `expl3` is the programming layer of `l3` and is loaded in the background by `xparse`.  The commands with `_` and `:` come from the `expl3` package.  It only *looks* complicated because the macros are verbose.  If you read through the code in the answer, it should be relatively easy to tell what everything is doing (in general) which is the advantage of the verbosity.

Comment: @egreg I beleive that I do have texlive 2012.

Answer (score 4):

Just a variation on Scott H.'s solution, for showing a perhaps better way to deal with the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\variation}{ s O{;} m m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \geoff_variation_check:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \geoff_variation_nocheck:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\msg_new:nnn { variation }
 { index~out~of~bounds }
 { You~have~requested~an~item~that~doesn't~exist }

\seq_new:N \l__geoff_item_list_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \geoff_variation_nocheck:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__geoff_item_list_seq { #1 } { #3 }
  \seq_item:Nn \l__geoff_item_list_seq { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \geoff_variation_check:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__geoff_item_list_seq { #1 } { #3 }
  \int_compare:nTF { #2 > \seq_count:N \l__geoff_item_list_seq }
   { \msg_warning:nn { variation }{ index~out~of~bounds } }
   { \seq_item:Nn \l__geoff_item_list_seq {#2} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\variation{3}{aaa;bbb;ccc;ddd;eee}

\variation[,]{3}{aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee}

\variation{1}{aaa}

\variation{2}{aaa}

\variation*{2}{aaa}

\end{document}
```

The `\NewDocumentCommand` instruction should be used to pass the arguments to an "internal" function. In order to better show how, I introduce a *-variant, so the control is passed either to `\geoff_variation_check:nnn` or to `\geoff_variation_nocheck:nnn`. The internal functions should be `protected`, since they do unexpandable actions (`\set...`).

The bulk of the action is splitting the argument into a sequence and returning the needed sequence item:

```
\seq_set_split:Nnn <sequence> { <tokens> } { <token list> }

\seq_item:Nn <sequence> { <integer expression> }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, the machine may generate a list like

```
{aaa;bbb; ; ccc}
```

which will yield a result not intended

```
\test{\variation{3}{aaa;bbb; ; ccc}} -> [ ]
```

Also, the parser (`;` in this case) may be active. These call for the prior normalization of the list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\makeatletter
% \getstrofnumber{<parser>}{<nr>}{<list>}
\robust@def*\getstrofnumber#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
  \@tempcnta\z@
  \def\@getstrofnumber##1#1##2\get@nnil{%
    \ifstrcmpTF{##1}\get@nil{%
      \endgroup
      \@latexerr{Item of serial number '#2' not found}\@ehd
    }{%
      \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
      \ifnum#2=\@tempcnta
        \endgroup##1%
        \expandafter\@gobble
      \else
        \expandafter\@iden
      \fi
      {\@getstrofnumber##2\get@nnil}%
    }%
  }%
  \edef\alist{\unexpanded{#3}}%
  \cpt@sttrue\cpt@csvnormalize[#1]\alist
  \expandafter\@getstrofnumber\alist#1\get@nil#1\get@nnil
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\pput#1{\char`{#1\char`} \space$\rightarrow$\space}
\noindent
\ttfamily
\pput{aaa;bbb; ; ccc}\getstrofnumber{;}{1}{aaa;bbb; ; ccc}\\
\pput{aaa;;bbb;ccc}\getstrofnumber{;}{2}{aaa;;bbb;ccc}\\
\pput{aaa;bbb;ccc}\getstrofnumber{;}{3}{aaa;bbb;ccc}\\
% \pput{aaa;bbb;ccc}\getstrofnumber{;}{4}{aaa;bbb;ccc}% error

\end{document}
```

[image]